# can not resolve views when i configure both InternalResourceViewResolver and XSLTViewResolver?

Tags: spring, xslt, spring-mvc

In my web application I use both JSPs and XSL. Configured view InternalResourceViewRelover for JSP and XSLTViewResolver for XSL files. Application is giving errors while resolving view, its always trying to resolve view with order 1 view resolver. If order 1 resolver is not able to resolve its not going for order 2 view resolver.

Below is the configuration

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="order" value="2" />
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xslt.XsltViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="order" value="1" />
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/xsl/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".xsl" />
    <beans:property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xslt.XsltView"/>
    <beans:property name="sourceKey" value="obj"/>
</beans:bean>
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220556/spring-3-mvc-multiple-view-resolversjsp-and-velocity

Comment: and this as well http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-viewresolver-chaining

Comment: swapping view resolver order didn't work. Both InternalResourceViewResolver,XsltViewResolver are extending UrlBasedViewResolver. Is this an issue?

Comment: I think thats the issue. Solution could be to use custom XsltViewResolver.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend class XsltView and override the method checkResource

```
package my.xslt;
import java.util.Locale;

public class XsltView extends org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xslt.XsltView {

    @Override
    public boolean checkResource(Locale locale) throws Exception {
        if (getServletContext().getResource(getUrl()) != null) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Change configuration

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xslt.XsltViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="viewClass" value="my.xslt.XsltView"/>
```

The cause of problem  is that the method checkResource always return true.