# How to give the view page in Spring controller if they are in different folders?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am having two folders in my `WEB-INF`.

**Folder1** contains 3 jsp like `page1.jsp , page2.jsp , page3.jsp` .

**Folder2** contains the `page4.jsp`.

In **dispatcher-Serlet.xml** I have configured like ,

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/folder1/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

In **Controller** ,

```
@RequestMapping(value="page4.html",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public  String getTransfer(){

    List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
    Hashtable<String , Object> map = MyHashtableClasss.getDetails;

    if(!map.isEmpty()){
        Set<String> keys = map.keySet();
        for(String key: keys){
                list.add(map.get(key).getUserName());
        }
    }
    model.addAttribute(list);

    return "page4";
}
```

How can I get **page4.jsp** in to the view . Because I didn't have that page4.jsp in Folder1.

In general , How can show the different `JSP`'s in differenf folders in `Spring`.Is that possible ? If not , what is the alternative.

Hope our stack user will help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1** Change

`<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/folder1/" />`

to

`<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />`

and return view with folder path

```
return "folder1/page4";
```

**2** Other way is to configure multiple view resolver beans and set the priority for each. Check following links for solution and limitations.

[Multiple View resolvers in spring mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288272/multiple-view-resolvers-in-spring-mvc)

[Spring MVC with multiple view resolvers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215402/spring-mvc-with-multiple-view-resolvers)

**EDIT**

The other way is to build your own view resolver by extending `InternalResourceViewResolver`. In extended view resolver you can add logic to scan sub folders and find the jsp file with the returned view name.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know this way .Is there any other way to give  the view page only as `return "page4"`;

Answer (score 0):

It's your choice what folder to specify for the ViewResolver.

If you specify /folder1, the JSPs will be resolved under folder1. If you don't, you'll need to specify /folder1 yourself when you want it.

You can use a function, or a constant, to do that for you if you really need to or it helps factoring..

```
public class Views {
    public static String legacy (String name) {return "folder1/"+name;}
    public static String modern (String name) {return "folder2/"+name;}
}
```

If you define Controllers in a separate application-context, you can hook them up with a separately-configured ViewResolver (with a different path).

But all this seems pretty obvious to me, I'm not really sure why you're asking such a question. Can Spring magically know that for one view, you want a different folder? I hope not, I'd prefer it to just work reliably in the folder that I specify.